# Entity Framework. Связи сущностей, унаследованных от одного базового класса

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Коллеги, подскажите.

Создаю отношение one-or-zero TO one-or-zero. Есть справочники "пользователи", "гонщики" и "тренеры". Исходные условия: Пользователь может быть гонщиком, а может и не быть. Может быть Тренером, а может и не быть. Гонщик может быть ассоциирован с Пользователем портала, а может и не быть ассоциирован. Тренер - аналогично. Создал такие модели и описал связь. Базовый класс `Person` будет использован для хранения информации общей для тренеров и гонщиков.

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Rider Rider { get; set; }
    public virtual Coach Coach { get; set; }
}

public class Rider : Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RiderName { get; set; }        
}

public class Coach : Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CoachName { get; set; }        
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
b.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.Rider)
    .WithOptionalDependent(r => r.User)
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("RiderId"));

b.Entity<User>()
    .HasOptional(u => u.Coach)
    .WithOptionalDependent(r => r.User)
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("CoachId"));
```

При создании миграции получаю ошибку:

> User: FromRole: NavigationProperty 'User' is not valid.
>
> Type 'Coach' of FromRole 'User_Coach_Target' in AssociationType 'User_Coach' must exactly match with the type 'Rider' on which this NavigationProperty is declared on.`

Если убрать наследование от класса `Person` и добавить виртуальное свойство `User` в классы `Coach` и `Rider`, то все ок, миграция генерируется как надо. Подскажите коллеги, с чем связан данная проблема, как ее решать и стоит ли вообще это делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема - в том, что вы пытаетесь две параллельные связи отобразить в одно навигационное свойство, к тому же расположенное в другом классе. Так делать нельзя.

Прямое исправление ошибки - создайте два отдельных свойства `User` в классах-наследниках.

Но, вообще говоря, со схемой данных у вас не все в порядке. Может ли гонщик быть тренером? Если может - то мы получаем два разных объекта `Person` с одинаковым именем - что странно. Если не может - то зачем в классе `User` у вас две разные связи?

В первом случае (гонщик может быть сразу пользователем и тренером) лучше отказаться от наследования и вынести `Person` в отдельную таблицу, сделав обязательным:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Rider
{
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Coach
{
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Rider Rider { get; set; }
    public virtual Coach Coach { get; set; }
}

b.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(p => p.User).WithRequired(u => u.Person);
b.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(p => p.Rider).WithRequired(r => r.Person);
b.Entity<Person>().HasOptional(p => p.Coach).WithRequired(c => c.Person);
```

Только будьте внимательнее с идентификаторами: "Optional - Required" связь обычно делается по первичным ключам, а для этого все айдишники кроме того что в `Person` не должны быть автогенерируемыми.

Во втором случае могу посоветовать просто объединить два поля из `User` в одно:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: благодарю, в целом понятно. Хочу уточнить про "две параллельные связи отобразить в одно навигационное свойство". Почему одно? Используется 2 разных класса. Каждый из них мапится на свою отдельную таблицу ( в контексте данных созданы `DbSet<Riders>` и `DbSet<Coaches>`). Получается связь будет между совсем разными таблицами (User <-> Coach и User <-> Rider). Как может наследование поломать модель?

Comment: *"Получается связь будет между совсем разными таблицами (User <-> Coach и User <-> Rider)."* - в этом и проблема: это одна сущность, а не две разных.